# What is the purpose of this current sense resistor in my arc lighter?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, current-measurement, high-voltage, reverse-engineering

I have an arc lighter similar to this one:

[image: example arc lighter]

The switch failed after a couple days (typical Chinese garbage), so I took the unit apart to replace it. Also, due to its operating frequency (~16Khz), it makes an appalling screeching sound that hurts my ears. So while I had it open, I decided I would attempt to modify it for a higher frequency.

By photographing both sides of the PCB; by using a multimeter; and by shining a light through the board, I managed to reverse-engineer it. Mostly.

My initial intention was to leave the micro in place, but insert a 555 timer between the chip and the MOSFET that drove the output coil. Its reset line would be asserted high by the chip's square wave output (by way of a diode, a resistor and a capacitor), and it would output a (thankfully inaudible) 22KHz signal to the MOSFET.¹ So far, so good.

My initial tests were promising, but in the end a pin broke off the chip and necessitated its replacement. Onto plan B then.

I figure I can just replace the (now defunct) chip with another microcontroller (specifically, a PIC or Atmel one), and write some firmware to perform the original functions, albeit at a higher frequency.

The microcontroller is unmarked, but fortuitously I have other microcontrollers with a compatible pinout. There is a problem, however. I don't understand the purpose of one of the connections on the board!

Here are the photographs I worked from. The high voltage transformer connects at the far right, and the 3.7V lithium battery at the left.² The lower image is flipped for convenience.

[image: photos]

From those pictures, I derived the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

My understanding of the circuit is as follows:

- The LTC chip is responsible for charging the battery.
- Voltage on the USB connector bypasses the power switch by way of Q1 and Q2, activating the microcontroller, in order that the charging lights may illuminate in sequence.
- The microcontroller monitors the USB voltage on pin 2, and refuses to trigger if a voltage is sensed.
- Pin 3 is for detecting when the battery is fully charged, in order to display the LEDs statically lit to indicate charging is complete.
- Pin 5 is the output pin, by which the chip outputs a 60% duty-cycle 15Khz square wave³ to the transformer via a MOSFET.

So, my question is...

- What is the purpose of the current sense resistor R12 (measured by pin 13)?

I have no way to know the model of microcontroller used in this product, or the internal workings of its firmware. So, what can be deduced from the circuit, in terms of **how pin 13 is likely to affect the microcontroller's behaviour?**

EDIT: I notice there is no back-EMF clamp diode on the transformer. Should there be?

---

¹ Unfortunately, I discovered that the 555 drives its output low when reset is low; driving the MOSFET on continuously, except when the square wave was present. There was some smoke, and the MOSFET *physically desoldered itself from the board!* Fortunately I was paying attention and disconnected it immediately; and I'm pretty sure no permanent harm was done. I added an NPN transistor and the problem went away.

² Yes, those dents happened during disassembly. Oops.

³ I measured this with an oscilloscope.

Comment: It's a current limiting resistor when FET is on.

Comment: I think not. First, it measures a tenth of an ohm, which would be a pretty ineffectual limit. And second, there is an ADC pin connected to it. It's a current sense resistor. The question is: why?

Comment: I don't deny the cpu is sensing it.  But that is not the purpose of R12.

Comment: 3.7V divided by 0.1Ω gives a current limit across this resistor of 37A. Are you suggesting that the MOSFET would be likely - in the absence of this resistor - to see thirty-seven amps of current from the Lipo? Besides, even if you're correct, I'm more concerned about the purpose of the sense pin, than of the resistor itself. My firmware doesn't need to care what the resistor itself is doing.

Comment: RON of MOSFET too.

Comment: Just buy a new one from a reputable source.

Comment: A new one would likely resonate at 15Khz just like the old one did, and hurt my ears. Which is why I was trying to modify it.

Comment: Tenth of an ohm is enough for pwm current mode sense for a current mode switching mode boost supply. The current limiting happens by the pwm controller. Current mode pwm is a common boost switch mode supply architecture

Comment: I *suppose* that technically, if you ignore the secondary transformer winding, you could consider the circuit to be a boost converter. But a boosted voltage at the sense pin isn't actually our intention, so detecting a high voltage there doesn't directly equate to success. How can this sense pin determine if the arc is being successfully generated?

Comment: Think about the FET current for each cycle. When the switcher is switching, the FET sees (some function of) the load current on Ids, and this is what is being sensed. While the feedback details depend on the device/controller, the idea is that every cycle the controller will adjust or limit the duty cycle as a function of Ids sense signal, which is a sawtooth with every cycle.

Comment: So basically, the firmware knows what amount of current it wants to put through the coil, and this desired value is a known constant. So if the battery is low, it will sense less current than that, and increase the duty cycle to compensate?

Comment: Sort of, a current sense like this is going to be fed directly into the feedback throughout every switching cycle (15khz), This is inherent to the operation of this supply architecture but is likely only partially implemented here. I highly suggest reading on switching power supplies with current mode pwm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a similar circuit used in my Gas operated water heater it also consist of an electric arc generating circuit and operates on two D type cell battery.

And have tested that circuit and I got to know that this kind of circuit need to change the Ton Time of the MOSFET to generate proper electric arc between their electrodes as fix duty cycle will not work efficiently in such case, as battery voltage will be gradually reduced Ton time should be increased.

So as I think in your case R12 provides a low resistive path for most of the current to flow to the ground and with a high resistor value like 4.7k R11 is used to sense voltage feedback so that it can vary the duty cycle accordingly.

Still, I am not 100% sure about this but you can test it with an oscilloscope and providing a variable power supply to the circuit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't measure this, because the original chip is now broken. It was the output pin that snapped off :(

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could, by artificially generating the square wave, perform tests (without the original chip) to give me a good idea of the correct behaviour with regards to this pin?

Comment: It's tricky but you can build a simple variable square wave output pulse generating circuit with a 555 timer. or if your oscilloscope supports outputting a variable square wave pulse you can use that also.

Comment: What I don't understand though, is how it's possible to sense correct operation by monitoring pin 13. How can the microcontroller "know" if the arc is happening?

Comment: The microcontroller doesn't know the arc is happening or not but it can sense that the power flowing from the primary side of the coil. and from that, it can manage the duty cycle.
Have created a simple simulation that might help to understand  https://www.tinkercad.com/things/a0UqSvhkEnm 
vary the input voltage and observe the change at the output voltage from 4.7K resistor.

Comment: Yes, I understand how the current through the MOSFET will affect the sensed voltage at pin 13. What I'm uncertain about, is how this helps the firmware perform its job effectively. Remember that its job isn't to generate a high current or voltage on the primary; but instead to cause an arc on the secondary. I guess maybe it knows how much current is needed in the primary to induce this effect, and will aim to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, that what I am trying to say. Just, for example, a perfect arc on the secondary side gives feedback voltage around 3v. And when the battery voltage drops probably feedback voltage will be drop now controller will increase Ton time and also increase Toff time allowing the capacitor to charge and discharge more through the primary. It looks like C2 is used as storage cap here.

Comment: Thank you. I will "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cheap alternative for a fuse. Its bad practice but I have seen it